# How to get Context when you call a method in a different class?

Tags: android, android-context

So basically, I have a method that requires a `Context` in order to perform several tasks.

```
public void openDatePicker() { Context c; }
```

I want to know, how to define a context of the method caller so I don't have to insert it as a parameter each time I call the method.

Comment: You can always call getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Lets have an basic understanding of **Context**.

**Context** allows access to application-specific resources and *classes*, as well as calls for application-level operations such as launching *activities*, *broadcasting* and *receiving intents*, etc.

A **Context** represents your environment. It represents the state surrounding where you are in your system.

An **Android** app has *activities*. **Context** is like a handle to the environment your application is currently running in. The *activity* object inherits the **Context** object.

So, how to access **Context** in your application ?

- **getContext**():  Returns the context within the currently active *Activity*. You can also use ***this*** for inflating layouts and menus, register context menus, instantiating widgets, start other *activities*, create new *Intent* within an **Activity** etc.

Example: **View**.**getContext**() returns the **Context** the view is currently running in. Usually the currently active *Activity*.

`View mView = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myLayout, myViewGroup);`

Or,

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
this.startActivity(mIntent);
```

- **getApplicationContext():** Returns the **Context** for the entire *application*, instead of the current *Activity* i.e. if you need a **Context** tied to the lifecycle of the entire *application*, not just the current *Activity*. This **Context** is widely used as it is safest to use as this **Context** exists for the lifespan of the *application*.

Example: Bind an application-wide *class*.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyPersistent.class);
MyServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();
if (mServiceConnection != null) {
    getApplicationContext().bindService(mIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

- **getBaseContext()**: Returns a **Context** from another **context** within *application* that you can access. This method has a limited usage.The method is relevant when you have a *ContextWrapper*.

ContextWrapper is, "Proxying implementation of **Context** that simply delegates all of its calls to another **Context**. Can be subclassed to modify behavior without changing the original **Context**." (as per javadocs)..

Now, a question might arise ! How would one access the **Context** object inside of a *class* that does not extend *Activity* ? So, it can be achieved by :

- Passing **Context** as an object to other *class*: For a *class* that does not have an access to any of the **Context** mentioned above. **Context** can be passed to such *class* through its *constructor*.

Example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        context = getApplicationContext();
        new Helper(context);
    }
}

public class Helper {
    Context mContext;
    Helper(Context ctx){
        this.mContext= ctx;
    }
//Now you can use this mContext anywhere in your class.
}
```

And finally, to get **Context** anywhere in your *application* you can define a new *class* in your *application* :

```
public class MyContext extends Application {
    private static MyContext instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return instance;
        // or return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

In your *manifest* you need to add this *class* to the "*Name*" field in the "*Application*" tab, like this:

```
<application
android:name="com.example.app.MyContext "
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
.......
<activity
......
</activity>
```

To get **Context** anywhere in your application, i.e. in any *class* of your *project*, you can call the *function* of this *class*, like this:

```
MyContext.getContext();
```

This *function* will return a **Context** that you can use to carry out your tasks.

So, coming to your question. I guess the last two methods can solve your problem i.e passing the **Context** object to the *class* and define a new *class* that extends *Application*.

That's all @Achmad Naufal Syafiq. This is my best effort to help you out.

Comment: Splendid explanation, and i managed to do it. thank your very much.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by two ways..

### First

Make a class say `Functions` and make you public static method inside it.

```
public class Functions{

    public static void openDatePicker(Context c){ 
        // Do your work where you can use c as Context
    }

}
```

and call it Wherever you want like

```
Function.openDatePicker(MainActivity.this);
```

### Second

as @UmarZaii Suggested You can define it once in the constructor.

```
public class CustomDatePicker {

    private Context context;

    public ClassLocationModel(Context context) {
         this.context = context;
    }

    public void openDatePicker() {
         // Do your work where you can use "context" as Context
    }
}
```

and to you that you have to initialize this class once in your Activity

```
CustomDatePicker customDatePicker = new CustomDatePicker(MainActivity.this);

// to use its methods
customDatePicker.openDatePicker();
```

I hope it will Help.

Answer (score 1):

You can one of the many dependency injection libraries to inject not just context but any dependencies that you have in a particular file.

You can have a look at [Dagger2](https://google.github.io/dagger/) for example

[This](https://blog.mindorks.com/introduction-to-dagger-2-using-dependency-injection-in-android-part-2-b55857911bcd) will help you exactly to create different contexts

Comment: its a great solution, but does it really require another library just to do this? isn't there any ways to do this without external library? but thanks for the answer, i will definitely checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it once in the constructor so that everytime you want to use the method, you don't have to define it in the parameter. Try this.

```
public class CustomDatePicker {

    private Context context;

    public ClassLocationModel(Context context) {
         this.context = context;
    }

    public void openDatePicker() {
         //Use context that has been passed through constructor here
    }
}
```

So, basically the trick is to pass context in the parameter of the contructor only **ONCE** and you can repetitively use openDatePicker method without passing any context inside the parameter.

Comment: i've tried this before, it works but not quite what i want because it still require you to pass the Context in constructor.

Comment: @AchmadNaufalSyafiq What you are asking is impossible as when you are using methods that requires context, the context itself differs from each Activity. So the context must be passed in the parameter.